# how to check all probabilities in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq

for example we have an array of Integers Like

```
private int[] arr = new[] {10,5,5,6,4,5,7,3,8,2 };
```

and we have a key

```
private key =1;
```

the goal is fined all possibilities that meet the following rule:

key+[list of indexes] = 11;

for example the output should be something like this:

```
 [0] - [1],[2] - [1],[5] - [2],[5] - [1],[7],[9] - [8],[9]
```

to be more clear, we want to fined all combination of indexes in a proper way;

```
 key+arr[0]=11;
 key+arr[1]+arr[2] =11;
 key+arr[1]+arr[5]=11;
 key+arr[1]+arr[7]+arr[9]=11;
```

first i try LinQ way and No chance!
second i tried to handle this with a* algorithm , but i had no Luck.
then i tried to do this with Recursive call and again no proper results.

i know this is not that complex , and i expected myself to do this in 15 minutes. but Im really stucked here.

any help appreciated.

Comment: number `11` is fixed or a parameter? what is the maximum size of the `arr` ?

Comment: Sounds like a normal peice of homework to me..  How do YOU as a human do it, tell your computer to start there..

Comment: This is a variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: @BugFinder No man this is not homework - whats the relation of linq and a* algorithm in a Homework project?

Comment: @PhamTrung the real array is fixed and has 15 members

Comment: All in all, you  need to check 2^arraylength combinations. If you don't know how/where to start, try a binary approach. Each element in your array can either be included in the sum or not included (0 or 1). If you think about it that way, one possible way to do this should become obvious.

Comment: use a recursive function to which you pass a number and an array, at each step of the recursion check which elements are lower than the number you pass, subtract that value from the number, cut the array after the element you are at and call the function again. If an element matches exactly what you are left with, return the path you used to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion in your friend, here is an example to push you in the right direction. Add pepper and salt to taste

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(int[] set, int sum, string values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
    {
        int left = sum - set[i];
        string vals = set[i] + "," + values;
        if (left == 0)
        {
            yield return vals;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] possible = set.Take(i).Where(n => n <= sum).ToArray();
            if (possible.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in GetCombinations(possible, left, vals))
                {
                    yield return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private int[] arr = new[] {10,5,5,6,4,5,7,3,8,2 };

foreach (string s in GetCombinations(arr, 18, ""))
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All possible combinations of array is i = 2^n - 1, where n is array.Length .
Create custom `int[] massBits = new int[arr.Length]`, convert i to Binary, and summ only those elements, which indexes in massBits has 1. Add to list of combinations only those, who has resultSum equals to your sumOfIndexes.
Code is dirty, but works fine:

```
 int[] arr = new[] { 10, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 8, 2 };
        int key = 1;
        int sumOfIndexes = 11 - key;

        // Number of combinations (2^n-1)
        int NumOfCombinations =(int) Math.Pow(2, arr.Length) - 1;

        // Result
        List<List<int>> listOfCombinations = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfCombinations; i++)
        {

            int[] massBits = new int[arr.Length];
            // Convert index to binary
            int indexOfMass = i;
            for(int j = 0; indexOfMass > 0 ; j++)
            {
                int remainder = indexOfMass % 2;
                indexOfMass /= 2;
                massBits[j] = remainder;
            }
            // Take indexes of elements, which contains 1
            var elementToCombine = massBits.Select((bit, j) => bit == 1 ? j: -1).Where(index=>index != -1).ToList();
            // Sum all elements 
            int resultSum = elementToCombine.Sum(index => arr[index]);
            if (resultSum != sumOfIndexes) continue;
            listOfCombinations.Add(elementToCombine);
        }
        foreach (var list in listOfCombinations)
        {
            foreach (var el in list)
            {
                Console.Write(el + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```